# Chain Rule for Matrix Valued Functions

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Suppose I have three matrix-valued functions $M_1, M_2, M_3 \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ which are a function of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = M_1(x)M_2(x)M_3(x)y.
\end{equation}
How do I compute the gradient of $f$ w.r.t the variable $x$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$, in terms of the gradients of $M_1$,$M_2$ and $M_3$?

My tensor calculus is a bit weak, so a detailed explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here is my result for $f'(x,y)$: First some notation. By $M'$ I denote the matrix $(A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n)$ with $A_j = \frac{\partial M}{\partial x_j}$. Moreover, if $B = (B_1,\ldots,B_n)\in\mathbb R^{n\times n^2}$ (as $M'$ above) and $v\in\mathbb R^n$ I set $B\otimes v = (B_1v,\ldots,B_nv)\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. With this notation I get$$f'(x,y) = \left[M_1'\otimes M_2M_3y + M_1M_2'\otimes M_3y + M_1M_2M_3'\otimes y,\;M_1M_2M_3\right].$$

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just to make sure I'm 100% clear, at the end when you write $f'(x,y) =[A_1, A_2]$ (where $A_1, A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$) do you mean the matrix multiple of $A_1$ and $A_2?$

Comment: I don't know what you mean by matrix multiple. What I mean is just the $n\times 2n$ matrix $[A_1\,|\,A_2]$ with $A_1$ and $A_2$ as "entries". So, the first entry of $f'(x,y)$ is what you asked for.

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification, and thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial} \def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\GLR#1#2{\LR{\g{#1}{#2}}}
$Let $\e_k$ denote the $k^{th}$ cartesian basis vector, then the $k^{th}$ row of the $M_1$ is
$$\eqalign{
m_k^T = \e_k^TM_1 \qiq m_k = M_1^T\e_k
 \quad \big({\rm as\:column\;vector}\big) \qquad\qquad
}$$
Use index notation to calculate the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
f &= M_1M_2M_3y \\
f_k &= m_k^TM_2M_3y \\
\g{f_k}{x_i}
 &= \GLR{m_k^T}{x_i}M_2M_3y + m_k^T\GLR{M_2}{x_i}M_3y + m_k^TM_2\GLR{M_3}{x_i}y \\
 &= \LR{M_2M_3y}^T\GLR{m_k}{x_i} + m_k^T\GLR{M_2}{x_i}M_3y + m_k^TM_2\GLR{M_3}{x_i}y \\
}$$